# Rails param value decoding in strange format

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a strange issue which I am not able to figure out why this is happening for url decode for a "-" dash.

Here is the params processed on the debian server,
Check that the filename contains stange characters for dash "-".

```
Started GET "/attachments/download/55388/VE11%20FTART%20%e2%80%93%20Large%20model.pptx" for x.x.x.x at 2015-06-01 07:54:19 +0200
Processing by AttachmentsController#download as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"55388", "filename"=>"VE11 FTART â~@~S Large model.pptx"}
```

The same format in my development environment is decoded properly.

```
  Parameters: {"id"=>"55388", "filename"=>"VE11 FTART – Large model.pptx"}
```

Anyone know the issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: that's not a regular dash, that's a [utf dash](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm) . when it encodes it, it changes to `%e2%80%93`, which is its value.

Comment: Ok, but this utf dash is coming in my server only, and not in my development environment. :(

Comment: i'm guessing you uploaded a file that has that dash in its filename. just replace it with a regular dash. btw, the reason you're seeing `â~@~` instead is because your terminal is using ASCII or something

Comment: Thank You, Changed the vi terminal to show utf8 encoded.

Comment: I will now proceed with another check why rails cannot find the file with file name in server..! Does rails search file name based on this encoded value ? or ?